# find closed sets in a list

Tags: scala, set, subset

I have a list of sets (Scala) and would like to remove all supersets. E.g.

```
List(Set(1,2,3), Set(1,2), Set(2,1), Set(5,6), Set(5))
```

I would like to get the following list

```
List(Set(1,2), Set(5))
```

I wrote the following function - not sure how robust it is:

```
 def findClosedSets (array: Array[Set[Int]]) : Array[Set[Int]] = {
  val arrayRight = array.distinct
  val arrayLeft =  arrayRight
  arrayLeft.filter(j => arrayRight.filter(i => i.subsetOf(j)).length==1)
}
```

Comment: So what's your question? If you want your code reviewed, codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `filter` as follows

```
mySets.distinct.filter(s => mySets.forall(x => !x.subsetOf(s) || s == x))
```

Comment: `x => x == s || x != (x & s)`